# couple of question about : wcf self service , consumer/ producer

Tags: c#, wcf, producer-consumer

i have a couple of question.
1. in a wcf self service for inner network process comunication , how many calls can a        service handle at the minimum amount of time ?
2. does any one have an open source code for a generic wrapper for producer/consumer with a loadbalance or even a noraml example ?
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This will depend on many different factors such as what your "minimum amount of time" is, what you service does, latency, disk I/O if applicable, your InstanceContextMode, etc. Too broad of a question to answer specifically, but WCF as a platform can handle many thousands of calls per second depending on your hardware.
2. Take a look at the [IDesign.net code library](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11). There are MANY examples, several of which use self hosting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. i know that wcf service on iis can handle up to 100K ( depending on hardware) is it the same on self hosting?

Comment: Absolutely, in my experience self hosting outperforms IIS. Whichever way you go, make sure you do your own performance/scalability testing to verify your architecture. Good luck!